# DriveResource.listParents does not work

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am developing an application for Android, where I need to get the list of parents of a file taken from google Drive.

I correctly obtain the DriveId using Drive.DriveApi.newOpenFileActivityBuilder(), but when I use DriveResource.listParents I obtain an empty list even if the resource have a parent.

I use the same GoogleApiClient for  Drive.DriveApi.newOpenFileActivityBuilder() and  DriveResource.listParents, so i do not think that is a scope problem.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE_DRIVE_FILE_PICKER) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         mSelectedFileDriveId = (DriveId)    data.getParcelableExtra(OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
      } else {
         setResult(Constants.RESULT_CODE_KO);
         finish();
      }
   }
}

...

private ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult> metadataBufferCallback = new ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {
   @Override
   public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult result) {
      if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
         SDKUtils.showMessage(thisActivity, "Impossible salvare l'ultima posizione aperta in Google Drive");
          return;
      }
      MetadataBuffer metadataBuffer = result.getMetadataBuffer();
      // HERE I OBTAIN AN EMPTY OBJECT
   }
};

...

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
              .setAccountName(driveAccontName)
              .addApi(Drive.API)
              .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
              .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
              .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

...

DriveFile driveFile = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(getGoogleApiClient(), mSelectedFileDriveId);
driveFile.listParents(GoogleApiClient apiClient).setResultCallback(metadataBufferCallback);
```

Have any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: Does your app have access to the parent folders?

Comment: Thank for the response!

Yes, when I use Drive.DriveApi.newOpenFileActivityBuilder() my app can access to parent folder. But I don not know if this implies that I can use driveFile.listParents.

If not, where can I enable access to parent folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**so i do not think that is a scope problem.**

It's exactly that - Scope problem !!!

Google Drive Android API provides only drive.file and drive.appfolder scope.

File scope means access only to those files which the user chooses from your application. The `Drive.DriveApi.newOpenFileActivityBuilder()` dialog will let the user browse through the whole drive but your application will be granted access to only those file or folder which the user specifically `Select`'s.

Suppose you have following folder structure on your drive -

```
    /root
      |
      +---books
          +---c++
              +---programming_gems.pdf
              +---c++_notes.docs
```

Now using Drive.DriveApi.newOpenFileActivityBuilder() you pick up programming_gems.pdf.
Your app has now obtained access to that pdf. You can retrieve the file and its metadata.
But your app won't be able to obtain access to its parent folder, c++ in this case.
Why? because the user has not yet given access to c++ folder; only a specific file within
that folder. This makes sense also; otherwise you can retrieve any file from that folder
leaving your user worried.

Pick up c++ folder using the same Drive.DriveApi.newOpenFileActivityBuilder(). Now if your 
app tries to retrieve the parent folder of programming_gems.pdf, it is granted access.

Try one more thing now; try to list the contents of c++ folder itself. What wil be returned to
your app? - only programming_gems.pdf. Why, because the user has not granted access to the other
file, c++_notes.docs.

I hope am clear.

P.S.

1. By the way, to select between picking up files or folder, you have to set the mime type.
   See the following code for e.g.,

   ```
   if (openFolder) {
       mime_type = new String[]{DriveFolder.MIME_TYPE};
   } else {
       mime_type = new String[]{};
   }

   IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
           .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
           .setMimeType(mime_type)
           .build(getGoogleApiClient());
   ```
2. If this scheme of scopes don't match your requirements you can alternatively use the Google Drive REST APIs - Read on - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25871516/1363471