# how to upload pdf in in google drive using android drive api ? give me a black file with correct not pages to be filled

Tags: android, pdf, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, drive

i stared using google drive api to up a pdf file to my drive after auth the account , a file is uploaded of pdf format

seems to be the problem when converting the file to pdf ! help me please
am i doing something wrong help pls thank you

```
        int a;
        String sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File myFile = new File(sdcard+"/Resume.pdf");
        try {
            FileInputStream fin;
            BufferedReader br;
            fin=new FileInputStream(myFile);
            br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(fin));
            OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream byt = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            while((a=br.read())!=-1)
            {
                byt.write(a);

            }
            outputStream.write(byt.toByteArray());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }






        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                .setTitle("New file pdf2")
                .setMimeType("application/pdf")
                .setStarred(true).build();

        // create a file on root folder
        Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                .createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, driveContents)
                .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
    }
}.start();
```

> `and used google drive demo homebaseActivity` [Link](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/BaseDemoActivity.java)

[image]

Comment: Did you check the logs if your code have successfully retrieve the content of the pdf? You may want to check this [Google Drive Android API – upload file to existing folder](http://wiki.workassis.com/google-drive-android-api-upload-file-to-existing-folder/) and [Android Create a file picker](http://wiki.workassis.com/android-create-a-file-picker/) to check if you have a proper code implementation. You may check this related SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37390212/5995040), that also provided the same tutorial for his solution. Hope this information helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot when i tired to open the the blank pdf file using text editor i found a large sequence of text , its seems to be  a problem in formatting i suppose, code seems to be good as i refereed the the above link to code

Comment: Have you solved your problem as i am also stuck in this please let me know if you have implemented the same