# How to upload files on Google drive with progress bar in Android

Tags: android, file-upload, android-progressbar, google-drive-android-api

I want to upload media files to g drive from my android app .
First it should show all google accounts and on selecting any it should start uploading file or files with progress update .
I tried to find over here and other forums but didnt get much to do it with progress bar . Can anyone provide me any reference sample code or link to do so.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried? If you want a progress bar only I would implement the AsyncTask as per [the documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and in the onProgressUpdate method I would update the progress of the progress bar.

Possible duplicate: [Upload progress listener not fired (Google drive API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986602/upload-progress-listener-not-fired-google-drive-api)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385591/how-to-upload-a-file-to-google-drive-folder-using-android-google-drive-sdk      I have already tried and successfully saved file at GDrive.     But i need code to show progress.

Comment: To update progress bar i need actual progress that how much file has been uploaded. I don't know how to.